# Would a question asking to identify a plug be on topic?

Tags: support, identification

I don't really ask questions here very often, and I want to know if a question asking to identify a certain proprietary connector would be on topic?

Comment: Identification of components is seen regularly on the stack and as long as pictures and description is clear it is usually no issue. Don't turn it into a shopping question by asking where to buy it, that would render the question off topic.

Comment: Doesn't matter, some bas***ds will still flag it as off topic.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Olin's answer about photo quality / size also make sure to include something in the photo to give an idea of dimensions because distances are of course hard to judge from a photo alone.  For example in a quesion [DRO scales 4-pin connector identification](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/61127/dro-scales-4-pin-connector-identification) I asked a while back I included a ruler in the photo along with some other measurements made using calipers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is fine.  However beware that the question might be closed if insufficient information is given.  Make sure to include a decent photograph that is *clear*, *detailed* and *properly cropped* to what you are trying to show.  All too often someone takes a unfocused picture with the item in question small and in the middle, but still dumps the full 10 Mpix image here.  The rules for decent and respectful presentation don't go away just because you want the answer badly.

In some cases, it can be useful to show a wider picture of the context the the part is being used in.  Also tell us what you know about the equipment and its application regime.  For example, it could be quite useful to know this where a microphone is expected to be plugged in, as apposed to something coming from a custom sensor, a antenna, a power supply, etc.

Comment: Well I'm a photographer so this will be no problem :)